# history.push changes url, but component is not rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, history

Why is the `Dashboard` component not rendered after `history.push("/dashboard")` changes the url to `/dashboard`?

[Gif showcasing the issue](https://i.gyazo.com/3063e6b9f45db9070d967c3f88b939ef.mp4), as you can see, I have to manually click the refresh button in order to trigger the re-render.

---

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Router from "./Router";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router />,
  rootElement
);
```

LoginForm.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

class LoginForm extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <form name="signup_form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
                </form>
        )
    }

}

export default LoginForm
```

Router.js

```
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory()

class Router extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <BrowserRouter >
                    <LoginForm history={browserHistory} />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
export default Router

function Dashboard() {
  return <h1>Dashboard</h1>
}
```

Comment: add the ```App``` component to your codesandbox please

Comment: I got an error because there's not the App.js file

Comment: edit : now there's no error, but you have to add your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are creating a custom history object that your `BrowserRouter` doesn't know about. The `LoginForm` component is manipulating one version of a `history` object while the router and routes are using the default `history` object used by the routing context. The login form is able to update the URL in the address bar but the outer routing context isn't able to see this change.

## Solution

Either remove the custom history and use the one provided by `BrowsserRouter` or or use the lower level `Router` component and pass the custom `history` object to it to be used in the routing context.

### Use standard history from routing context

Router.js

```
<BrowserRouter >
  <LoginForm/>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

LoginForm - decorate with the `withRouter` higher order component so it receives route props from the closest routing context.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class LoginForm extends Component {

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form name="signup_form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
      </form>
    );
  }

}

export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

#### Use custom history

```
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory()

class MyRouter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory} >
        <LoginForm />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
export default MyRouter;
```

And still decorate `LoginForm` with the `withRouter` HOC so the route props are passed.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class LoginForm extends Component {

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form name="signup_form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
      </form>
    );
  }

}

export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

#### Suggestion

As written, the `LoginForm` component will ***always*** be rendered, this is probably not what you intended. I suggest just moving it into a route so the route props will be passed.

```
<Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change the Router. If you write that way, LoginForm will always render.

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"

class Routers extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work ... Can you explain how changing BrowserRouter to Router would fix the issue, and what the issue even is for that matter?

Comment: It should work. Do you pass in the browerHistory as shown? ```<Router history={browserHistory}>```

Comment: What you wrote is identically to my code [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58587923/7123519). `BrowserRouter` is equivalent to `Router history={history}`. Yes, I do do that

Comment: Not exactly. The reason is BrowserRouter has its own history. creating another history and push from it will not change router history.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch the another problem. I have edit my answer. Try it pls. @Sebastian Nielsen

Comment: Now the dashboard correctly renders after `history.push`. However, I am still confused as to why my original piece of code doesn't work.

Comment: Well, as I explain earlier, the two router are not exactly the same. you need to use the browerRouter's history for push to work, instead of create a new history and use it. Since you code works now, would you accept my answer?